# passing new value string from a bool method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to determine if the user clicks Admin or User radiobutton when registering. I think i should append it to the end of the line on the text file where the name and password is, but how would i do it? Here is the relevant code:

Radio Button Check

```
public bool radioButtons()
{
    string usertypebutton;
    if (!userButton.Checked && !adminButton.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (userButton.Checked)
        {
            usertypebutton = "User";
        }
        else
        {
            usertypebutton = "Admin";
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Streamwriter for registering:

```
public void mySW()
{
    string path = @"C:\Other\myFile.txt";
    string userName = userNameBox.Text;
    string password = passwordBox.Text;
    string usertype = usertypebutton;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Username: {0} Password: {1} Type: {3}" , userName, password, usertype);

        // No need to close nor dispose your StreamWriter.
        // You're inside a using statement for that!
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Thanks for registering! \n\nYou may now log in!", "Registration SuccessFul");
    Application.OpenForms[0].Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Logging In:

```
 private void logonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Loads your users storage
    var users = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt");

    // Creates the line with username + password
    var usernamePassword = String.Format("Username: {0} Password: {1}", userNameBox.Text, passwordBox.Text);

    // Locates the user on your storage
    var userFound = users.SingleOrDefault(_u => _u.Equals(usernamePassword));

    if (userFound != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, " + userNameBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have entered incorrect details\n\nPlease try again");
        userNameBox.Text = "";
        passwordBox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

So (I think) essentially i want to pass the value usertypebutton from radiobutton method, to the SW. How would i do it, as i'm already passing a boolean value?

Anthony

Comment: You mentioned you got a previous question sorted out in your post.  1) That's off-topic to this question and is a waste of time to read.  2) You never actually accepted the answer in the previous question.  If you got your answer then you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: I am confused as to what the issue is.  If you are already passing a bool, why can't you pass a string instead that holds Admin or User?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the return type to a string and return the string "ERROR" if neither check box was selected. In mySW(), I would check to see if "ERROR" was returned before opening the StreamWriter and if it does just exit the function so that nothing is done.

Answer (score 0):

Do not write unencrypted, plain text passwords anywhere.  It is horrendously insecure and could get you in a lot of trouble if you are ever hacked.  You really need to look around for a password encryption policy you trust before anything else.

As for your actual question, you already have:

```
writer.WriteLine("Username: {0} Password: {1} Type: {3}" , userName, password, usertype);
```

Just change it to take in the string value of the radio button selected and you can write out Admin or User.